# Why is my Autocomplete not doing the select first and mustmatch

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3

Why is my autocomplete not doing the `selectFirst` and `mustMatch`? Do I need a work around for this?

I'm using  version 1.8.9 of jQuery.

Here is my setup code:

```
$(function () {
     $("#SelectedSchool").focus().autocomplete({
         source: function (request, response) {
             $.ajax({
                 url: "/School/FindShools", 
                 type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                 data: {
                    searchText: request.term, 
                    maxResults: 10, 
                    autofill: true, 
                    selectFirst: true, 
                    highlight: true 
                 },
                 success: function (data) { 
                    response($.map(data, function (item) { 
                        return { 
                           label: item.SchoolName, 
                           value: item.SchoolName, 
                           id: item.SchoolId
                        } 
                    })) 
                 }
             })
         },
         select: function (event, ui) { 
             SchoolID = ui.item.id.toString();
             $("#SelectedSchoolID").val(ui.item.id.toString());
         }
     });
});
```

Comment: @ShyamBhimani It's nice that you're editing out greetings, but please, while you're editing, please edit the rest of the post as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `selectFirst` and `mustMatch` options are gone in the [jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) plugin. They were available in de [bassistance.de autocomplete plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/), which has been deprecated.

Here's a [migration guide to the new jQuery UI autocomplete](http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/autocomplete-migration-guide).

Quoted from that guide:

> - selectFirst: Similar to autoFill (at the top of this list), this option is gone and has now immediate replacement, nor a need for one. The behaviour for selecting values is solid enough to make this option redundant.
> - mustMatch: Gone, but easy to implement with the select event. Once more, the combobox provides an example for that.

---

**UPDATE**
The link to the migration guide isn't working today (2011-04-09). I could fortunately open the site from cache, so I've saved it, [zipped it and put it up for anyone to download](http://www.sharpedgesoftware.com/Downloads/Autocomplete_Migration_Guide.zip).

Hope this helps

*(2011-04-10: The Migration guide link works again)*

Comment: Hah! I tried yesterday night and it worked (I copy/pasted the quote from the migration guide only yesterday). It seems to be down today but the link is correct (it's on the bassistance.de autocomplete page as well). I'm afraid you'll have to try later :(

Comment: @bhushanvinay - Just checked and the link still doesn't work, but I've update my answer with a link where you can download the guide from.